# Can you load a groovy file in one Jenkins stage; run functions; and share data using a @groovy.transform.Field across multiple Jenkins stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Say that you have a groovy file:

```
@groovy.transform.Field
def data = [:]

def function1() {
    data.put(5)
}

def function2() {
    data.each {num} ->
    println("${num}")
}

return this
```

and you want to call the functions in the following Jenkinsfile; can you load the groovy file in one stage, pass the loaded file to a second stage and call a function? I have tried the following:

```
pipeline {
    stage('One') {
      steps {
        script {
            def rootDir = pwd()
            def script = load "${rootDir}/script.groovy"
            script.function1()
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Two') {
      steps {
        script {
            script.function2()
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed achieve this as the [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script) applies.

In order for it to work in the declarative pipeline you will just need to define the `script` parameter as a global parameter so it will be accessible in other steps:

```
pipeline {
   stage('One') {
     steps {
        script {
           def rootDir = pwd()
           // Don't use 'def' here - so it will be a global variable
           script = load "${rootDir}/script.groovy" 
           script.function1()
       }
     }
   }
   stage('Two') {
      steps {
        script {
            script.function2()
       }
     }
   }
}
```

For readability you can also define it as a global parameter outside the `pipeline` scope:

```
def script

pipeline {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a look at that page previously, but it didn't sink in that that's what the example was trying to show.